# When I try to lock the mutex recursively, no deadlock occurs

Tags: c++, std, mutex, deadlock

Why does the following code not deadlock.

I try to use cpp to construct a deadlock situation, but why does the following code not deadlock

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>

class Request {

public:
  void process() {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
    print();
  }

  void print() {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
    std::cout << "108392" << std::endl;
  }

private:
  std::mutex mutex_;
};

int main() {
  Request req;
  req.process();
}
```

I expect my code to deadlock

Comment: Please explain your expectation, why do you expect a deaflock? [std::mutex::lock](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex/lock): *If lock is called by a thread that already owns the mutex, the behavior is undefined*. UB does not mean a deadlock.

Comment: Attempting to lock a `std::mutex` from a thread that has already locked the mutex will invoke undefined behavior.

Comment: Libstdc++ explicitly detects this, prints a warning and ignores the call to lock

Comment: @twn29004 is anything missing or unclear in my answer below ?

Answer (score 9):

From [cppreference.com (`std::mutex::lock`)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex/lock):

> If lock is called by a thread that already owns the mutex, **the
> behavior is undefined**: for example, the program may deadlock.

*(emphasis is mine)*

Since it is UB ([Undefined Behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)), anything can happen, including (but not necessarily) a deadlock.

A side note:
If you do need re-entrancy with a mutex, you can use [`std::recursive_mutex`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/recursive_mutex).